# How to share on Tumblr with sharekit

Tags: ios, tumblr, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit https://github.com/ShareKit to share image on tumblr.
But problem is when I register app on tumblr at http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps, I get a API key. But there is no place to put this key on ShareKit configurator file.

Then I ignore that key, run the app and choose share on tumblr, this "login error" appear
"The service encountered an error. Please try again later".
Any body has the same problem? how can share on tumblr using sharekit?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Configuration): "ShareKit is intended to be incorporated as a submodule, and we moved configuration out of the ShareKit source code. This is a significant change, if you were used to configure it old SHKConfig.h way"?

Comment: I mean there is no place in the DefaultSHKconfigutor to put the API key of tumblr. Only has others (facebook, twitter, blah blah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the newest Sharekit version fixed this

Comment: i still unable to access tumblr .....you want to say that there is no configuration required for tumblr,......

Comment: It seems like Sharekit doesn't work anymore with tumblr. Now it uses new authentication type, sharer in ShareKit doesn't support it.